# Can a dense layer on many inputs be represented as a single matrix multiplication?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Denote `a[2, 3]` to be a matrix of dimension 2x3. Say there are 10 elements in each input and the network is a two-element classifier (cat or dog, for example). Say there is just one dense layer. For now I am ignoring the bias vector. I know this is an over-simplified neural net, but it is just for this example. Each output in a dense layer of a neural net can be calculated as

```
output = matmul(input, weights)
```

Where `weights` is a weight matrix 10x2, `input` is an input vector 1x10, and `output` is an output vector 1x2.

My question is this: Can an entire series of inputs be computed at the same time with a single matrix multiplication? It seems like you could compute

```
output = matmul(input, weights)
```

Where there are 100 inputs total, and `input` is 100x10, `weights` is 10x2, and `output` is 100x2.

In back propagation, you could do something similar:

```
input_err = matmul(output_err, transpose(weights))
weights_err = matmul(transpose(input), output_err)
weights -= learning_rate*weights_err
```

Where `weights` is the same, `output_err` is 100x2, and `input` is 100x10.

However, I tried to implement a neural network in this way from scratch and I am currently unsuccessful. I am wondering if I have some other error or if my approach is fundamentally wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is wondering, I found the answer to my question. This does not in fact work, for a few reasons. Essentially, computing all inputs in this way is like running a network with a batch size equal to the number of inputs. The weights do not get updated between inputs, but rather all at once. And so while it seems that calculating together would be valid, it makes it so that each input does not individually influence the training step by step. However, with a reasonable batch size, you can do 2d matrix multiplications, where the input is `batch_size` by `input_size` in order to speed up training.

In addition, if predicting on many inputs (in the test stage, for example), since no weights are updated, an entire matrix multiplication of `num_inputs` by `input_size` can be run to compute all inputs in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. You can mark your answer as the answer I guess.